# Excel COM Object in PowerShell

Tags: excel, powershell, com, sharepoint-online

SharePoint Online has a mostly undocumented method of populating a list of SharePoint Online sites that an administrator pushes out to its users.  Based on the presence/values of some registry keys, the client workstation knows when to ask SharePoint Online for an updated list of the SharePoint sites.

The problem I'm having is that the only way to kick off that process is by opening the `FILE - Open` or `FILE - Save` dialog box in an Office application (Excel 2013 in my case).
[I'd love to be wrong about this, but I can't find any other way this works.]

After opening that dialog box, it checks the registry keys for timestamps and URLs and if everything is cool it grabs the updated list of published SharePoint sites.

I'm trying to write a simple PowerShell script that people can run in order to force this process.  My question is simple -- how do I close the dialog box that I'm opening in the last line of the code posted below?

```
$global:excel = new-object -com Excel.Application
$excel.visible = $true
sleep 1
$excel.GetOpenFilename()
```

My script never leaves the `GetOpenFilename()` method until the user manually hits Cancel.  I'd like to press `Cancel` programmatically.

Any suggestions?  Am I going about this the wrong way?  Does anyone know what underlying method is being called to populate the SharePoint Sites folder when this dialog box opens and is there any way I can just call that directly in my script?

Comment: If you have a sharepoint list embedded in the document, you should be able to do something like `$Excel.ActiveSheet.ListObjects([listindex]).Refresh()`